# Unit test Jasmine issue "Failed: XMLHttpRequest is not defined" for Angular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Angular CLI has automatically created a failed unit test for a component and I have a problem to fix it.

Messages:
1) WkplAmFindTabsComponent should create
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'injector' of null"

and

"Message:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null"

When I have added

```
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

a next failure is: 
"1) WkplAmFindTabsComponent should create
  Message:
    Failed: XMLHttpRequest is not defined"

My component uses a router from a constructor and a method from service from an input.

```
@Input() makeHref: (param: object) => string;
constructor(private router: Router) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.url = this.router.routerState.snapshot.url;
}
```

My component unit test:

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ WkplAmFindTabsComponent ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WkplAmFindTabsComponent);
        const component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're injecting the `router`, I am thinking you need to import it. This is also the first time I am seeing `resetTestEnvironment()` and `initTestEnvironment` but I will ignore it.

Try:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule], // add this line !!
            declarations: [ WkplAmFindTabsComponent ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WkplAmFindTabsComponent);
        const component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

A good source on testing routing: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/